# Where is a good place for the license plate light on a 1991 Ford F-250?

Tags: ford, truck, f-250, lights

I have a 1991 Ford F-250 here that doesn't have a light on the license plate. It's not obvious where the lights were before, but it looks like may have been replaced with sockets for a trailer's wiring plug.

To keep the sockets as they are, where else can I install a lamp, and have it still be protected from boots and rocks? (This is a work truck for a builder.)

Answer (score 3):

What about these lights as I discovered in [this question](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/q/973/85)

[image]

[CHROME WHITE LED LIGHT NUMBER PLATE SCREW BOLTS](http://cgi.ebay.co.uk/CHROME-WHITE-LED-LIGHT-NUMBER-PLATE-SCREW-BOLTS-1-pair-/180526358897?pt=UK_CarsParts_Vehicles_CarParts_SM&hash=item2a0835a171)

[Or this one](http://www.etrailer.com/Trailer-Lights/Optronics/LPL55CB.html)

[image]

Looks like you just drill a hole for [this](http://www.pmlights.com/products.cfm?cId=2&fId=9&pId=2119) one

[image]

Answer (score 1):

how about something like this? [http://www.amazon.com/LED-License-Plate-Light-Strip/dp/B0013NJX7Y](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0013NJX7Y)