# Requirements for number plate illumination (UK) (Are LED Bolts good enough for cars?)

Tags: lights

Could someone tell me what the law states with regards to the illumination of number plates in the UK?
(i.e. number of lights, intensity in mcd (milli-candella)?)

I have installed a reversing camera on my car in the place of a number plate lamp holder and no longer have enough space to reinstall a bulb so I want to replace both lamp holders with 'LED Bolts' similar to this:

[image]

[CHROME WHITE LED LIGHT NUMBER PLATE SCREW BOLTS](http://cgi.ebay.co.uk/CHROME-WHITE-LED-LIGHT-NUMBER-PLATE-SCREW-BOLTS-1-pair-/180526358897?pt=UK_CarsParts_Vehicles_CarParts_SM&hash=item2a0835a171)

But all of these products are sold for scooters and motorbikes and I want to make sure my car would still be road worthy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rules you are after are the road vehicle lighting regulations 1989 ([link](http://www.legislation.gov.uk/uksi/1989/1796/contents/made)).

Particularly [this page](http://www.legislation.gov.uk/uksi/1989/1796/schedule/15/made).

Unfortunatly, as usual, they are pretty vague:

> Such that the lamp or lamps are capable of adequately illuminating the rear registration plate

and

> An approval mark

I can't see any minimum rating there - I don't think any are specified in candela, it's usually a wattage IIRC.

Comment: I suppose vague is good in that it doesn't rule them out! I'll install and see how they look (illuminate) compared to other cars and hopefully that will be OK. That site looks very useful; Thank You!

Comment: Strange. "Adequate" is a pretty subjective matter.